# Inspect hidden messages in queue

Tags: azure-queues, azure-storage-emulator

When adding a message to a queue, if the initialVisibilityDelay is set, eg initialVisibilityDelay = 10 minutes, I cant see it. Is there any way to inspect messages that are not visible?

I am unable to see it in the Azure Storage Explorer.